# How to get AVD emulator on top of android studio window

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Unable to find an option to put avd emulator window inside or on top of android studio window so that don't have to switch window while debugging.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/716394/mac-osx-keep-window-on-top, it seems Apple's idea was for you to resize the window to keep them visible side by side, or having an additional monitor.

Answer (score 1):

On AVD emulator on the bottom right corner there are 3 dots, click on that, a window will pop up, from there go to settings and you will a button to keep the AVD always on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Just reduce the size of the Android Studio window to 2/3 or half of the screen, and put the emulator to the other side.

Similarly, you can put your web browser and Android Studio side by side, so that you can look at relevant documents or codes on the web when typing in your codes at the same time.